# Implemented Variance equation, But they don't have same results

Tags: python, statistics

I have a this equation: $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + 2Cov(X+Y)+ Var(Y)$.
I have implemented these in python but the results are not the same.
Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code?

````
X = [random.randint(1,20) for i in range(10)]
Y = [random.randint(1,20) for i in range(10)]
X_PLUS_Y = [X[i]+Y[i] for i in range(len(X))]
print(statistics.variance(X_PLUS_Y)) # 108.23333333333333
print(statistics.variance(X)+2*Covariance(X,Y)+statistics.variance(Y))#105.07777777777777```
````

Comment: What are `X` and `Covariance`?

Comment: Sorry about the mistake, this my first question. Covariance is a function to calculate the covariance of two lists.

Comment: If you wrote ti yourself, can you include the code in the question? And also, where does the `statistics` module come from?

Comment: Which variance did you use for your calculations? It might be that you used sample variance instead of population variance, which actually gives that kind of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely something wrong with the way you calculate the covariance. If we use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import statistics
np.random.seed(123)

X = np.random.randint(1,20,10)
Y = np.random.randint(1,20,10)
X_PLUS_Y = X+Y

The variance of X + Y:

np.var(X_PLUS_Y,ddof=1)
147.4333333333333

statistics.variance(X_PLUS_Y.tolist())
147.43333333333334
```

Covariance should look like this:

```
np.cov(X,Y,ddof=1)
 
array([[47.56666667, 27.24444444],
       [27.24444444, 45.37777778]])
```

The off diagonal value is what we need, but you can already see the sum of this matrix is the variance, hence you have var(X) + 2*cov(X,Y) + var(Y):

```
X.var(ddof=1) + 2*np.cov(X,Y,ddof=1)[0,1] + Y.var(ddof=1)
147.4333333333333
```